# Value of partial derivatives at a point, when the tangent plane is known

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Knowing the equation of the tangent plane $\pi: 2x + y + 3z = 0$ at the point $(1, 1, 1)$ of a function $f(x, y)$, how can I find the values of $f'_x(1, 1)$ and $f'_y(1, 1)$?

I thought of this: since I know the equation of the plane, then I know it comes from

$$\pi: z=f(1, 1) + f'_x(1, 1)(x-1) + f'_y(1, 1)(y-1)$$

Thence by comparison I shall say, since $z = -\frac{2}{3}x - \frac{1}{3}y$

$$0 = f(1, 1) - f'_x(1, 1) - f'_y(1, 1)$$

and most of all

$$f'_x(1, 1) = -\frac{2}{3} \qquad f'_y(1, 1) = -\frac{1}{3}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: What is $f_x'$ for you? Do you mean partial derivative of $f$ w.r.t to $x$? In general, people just use $f_x$ for that.

Comment: If that is what you meant then your argument is correct.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak Yes, I mean the partial derivative wrt x

Answer (score 1):

The solution is correct but I'd add perhaps a little bit more rigor.

Since $(1,1,f(1,1))$ touches the plane we have $f(1,1)=-1\,.$ The equation you labelled with $\pi$ holds for all $x,y,z$ in the plane. Choosing two points
$(2,0,0)$ and $(2,2,-2)$ in the plane gives us a system
\begin{align}
-\tfrac 43&=-1+f'_x-f'_y\,,\\[2mm]
-2&=-1+f'_x+f'_y
\end{align}
that has the unique solution $f'_x=-2/3\,,f'_y=-1/3\,.$

Comment: Thank you really much!